# Setting contentview after button click

Tags: java, android, button, onclick

When my application starts I want to have a start game button. When the button is pressed I want another activity to be shown.

In XML I Setup the button like this:

```
<Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Start"
        android:id="@+id/bttnStart"
        android:onClick="startGame"
        />
```

And this is the Java function:

```
public void startGame(View v ){

       setContentView(R.layout.activity_start_menue);

}
```

My app crashes when I click the button.

Comment: Try to inflate the layout instead of setting setVontentView.

Comment: bad idea. try navigating to a different screen

Comment: post your logcat and explain what you want to do in details please...

Comment: Can you please tell what are you trying to achieve by doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Calling `setContentView()` multiple times is dangerous, and doesn't always work. There can be hierarchy conflicts, and inefficiencies that result from instantiating views multiple times. It's also not that helpful, because you're not in control of the container that the layout expands into.

### Here is the proper way to do it.

Android provides a built-in mechanism for view-switching called a `ViewFlipper`. Instead of calling `setContentView()` for the layout you want to swap in, you can tell the `ViewFlipper` object to either `showNext()` or `setDisplayedChild(int)`.

Here's how you would accomplish that in your `main.xml`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ViewFlipper xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             android:id="@+id/viewflipper"
             android:orientation="vertical"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="fill_parent">
  
    <!-- The ViewFlipper can change through its direct children -->

    <!-- Child 0 -->
    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Start"
        android:id="@+id/bttnStart"
        android:onClick="startGame"/>

    <!-- Child 1 -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/activity_start_menu"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Here's the menu!"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</ViewFlipper>
```

Note that the views being flipped through are **direct** children of the `<ViewFlipper>` that you are using. FYI, you can have more than just two views.

Now onto the Java code in your `MyActivity'.

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    ViewFlipper viewFlipper;
    /**
     * Called when the activity is first created.
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        viewFlipper = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.viewflipper);
    }

    /**
     * Switches to the activity_start_menu LinearLayout
     * specified in the ViewFlipper.
     */
    public void startGame(View v) {

        //First way -- use showNext() & showPrevious()
        viewFlipper.showNext();

        //Second way -- use setDisplayedChild(int) where int is
        // the index of the view starting from 0
        //In this case, there are two. 0 is the button,
        // and 1 is the menu layout.
        viewFlipper.setDisplayedChild(1);

        //You can also do fancy animations to switch between views.
        // Check out the methods accessible and experiment with them!
    }
}
```

You should end up with something like this:

[image: Test ViewFlipper]

Comment: But is there a way to change the activity? I have 2 different activity described in XML.

Comment: So there is a difference between layouts and activity's. If you have two different activity's, you have two different java activity's running. Activity's need a layout to go with them, so you can even stick with one layout. If you want one xml layout per activity, then you have to 1) setContentView to that layout, 2) call an intent to the second activity, & 3) make sure you have the activity defined in manifest.

Btw, if I've helped you, please vote me up. thx :)

Answer (score 0):

Start activity
Draft:

```
onCreate()
setContentView(//layout 1);
Button lButton = (Button) findview....
lButton.setOnClickListener(...)
{
onClick()
{
setContentView(//layout 2);
}
}
```

Comment: How should I define the parameters for  setOnClickListener() method?

Comment: Its a draft pseudo code ;) I know it lacks some parameters etc semicolons and stuff like that.

Answer (score -1):

To start new activity you should use:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, YourActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Or if you wouldn't change activity use for eample viewswitcher to switch layout, fragments etc